# How do I reference the repository's hgrc sections from within my custom hook?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc, mercurial-hook

I've written a generic changegroup hook function that I would like to customize for each repository by setting some hgrc section variables, like so:

```
[my_hook_params]
name = whatever
version = 1.0
```

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah. [See 4.2 Reading Configuration Files](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi#Reading_configuration_files)